# Need help writing bash loop to delete one user on multiple servers

Tags: linux, bash

New to loop bash.
I need a script to read a txt file and delete a user on each listed server.
How would this look?

```
for user in $(cat /tmp/server-list.txt); do userdel -f $USERID; done
```

It fires, but does not find the User account on any of the servers (use 'ID' does not exist).  What am I getting wrong?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You have a list of servers, loop the list (with a very bad method) and get back users?? And why would a variable `$USERID` being set? You should share your whole script and tell us the whole picture. This is not answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are:

1. Trying to loop through a text file with a list of server IP addresses, each one on a new line
2. SSH to each server as the ubuntu user (feel free to change to your user) and you are trying to delete a single particular user (lets say "john smith") on each machine
3. All as one line

`USERID="john smith"; cat /tmp/server-list.txt | while read IP_ADDRESS; do ssh -q -n ubuntu@$IP_ADDRESS "userdel -f $USERID" ; done`

If you have multiple users and multiple servers, you would need to use a nested loop or an array

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is Bash, we can use `mapfile` to create an array from the file contents:

```bash
mapfile server </tmp/server-list.txt
```

Then we can loop over these servers:

```
for s in "${server[@]}"
do
    #something
done
```

Now we need to use the value of `$s` when we write the code where I put the placeholder "`#something`" (this can be a little tricky, because the "command" arguments to `ssh` are [combined into a string that's passed to `sh -c` on the server](/a/717536/112566)):

```
    ssh "root@$s" "userdel -f '${USERID//\'/\'\\\'\'}''"
```

(Assuming `$USERID` is set somewhere outside the script; that tricky substition is to deal with `'` characters that would otherwise confuse the remote shell)

Putting it all together:

```
read -p "Delete which user?" userid
mapfile server </tmp/server-list.txt
for s in "${server[@]}"
do
    ssh "root@$s" "userdel -f '${userid//\'/\'\\\'\'}''"
done
```

Answer (score -2):

`for user in $(cat /tmp/server-list.txt); do userdel -f $USERID; done`

Here `user` is a name of a loop variable. On each iteration of the loop you are setting it to a next line of `/tmp/server-list.txt` file.

That variable is not used anywhere in the loop. So the loop will execute same statement over and over as many times as there are lines in the file.

`$USERID` reads variable `USERID` which is not set in this piece of code. So, assuming you did not assign anything to this variable, the actual executed code would be

```
userdel -f
```

Reading lines from file 'server-list.txt' into variable 'user' is not really an error, but very confusing nonetheless. It is a style mistake which would give you a lot of headache if your loop would grow to a few commands.

Comment: `for user in $(cat ...)`  does not loop lines but words.